# @Scheduled con Spring

Tags: java, spring, cron

ando integrando @Screduled a Spring para que se me ejecute una tarea programada pero a la hora de probar la anotación con un sencillo ejemplo y ejecutar la aplicación en un servidor Tomcat en la consola no me aparece lo que mande a ejecutar para probar:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduledTasks {
    

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * *", zone = "America/Bogota")
    public void deactivateInscriptions() {
    
        System.out.println("Test");
        
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero es que cada 5 segundos me imprima "Test" para probar que esta funcionando pero no aparece nada en la consola, agradecería su ayuda, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que te estás perdiendo un bean para `TaskScheduler`

Puedes probar este ejemplo:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class Main {
    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler scheduler() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * *")
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("tick");
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) throws InterruptedException {
        try (GenericApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Main.class)) {
            ctx.start();
            Thread.currentThread().join();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya intente lo solicitado pero sigue sin funcionar, no me imprime nada en la consola y la verdad cuando utilizo la cron con Spring Boot utilizando el mismo método si me funciona hasta con el intervalo de cada 5 segundos no se la verdad por que en Spring no.

Comment: @SantiagoLorduy tienes razón sobre eso, echa un vistazo a mis correcciones

Comment: Me funciono muchas gracias pero solo cuando ejecuto la aplicación por consola y como haría para que se ejecute al arrancar la aplicación con un servidor?